# How to Dynamically Change size of Image in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I created a web service and had imagefield from the sitecore6.6.  Now i am want to change the width and height of image dynamically so that i have big image on the fly. There are almost 1000 pictures which require size change . Any help...

Answer (score 14):

You can use several query string parameters in the url of the image to let Sitecore modify the image. The image has to be a Sitecore Media item.

Here is a list of the supported query string parameters:

- w: Width in pixels
- h: Height in pixels
- mw: Maximum width in pixels
- mh: Maximum height in pixels
- la: Language (defaults to context language)
- vs: Version (defaults to latest version)
- db: Database name (defaults to context database)
- bc: Background color (defaults to black)
- as: Allow stretch (as=1)
- sc: Scale by floating point number (sc=.25 = 25%)
- thn: Thumbnail (thn=1)
- dmc: Disable media caching, both retrieval and storage (dmc=1)

In your case you can use for example the ?as=1&w=600 to get the image resized to 600px width.

You can also do this programmatically to set the MediaUrlOptions when creating the mediaUrl:

```
var mediaOptions = new MediaUrlOptions {AllowStretch = true, Width = 600};
var mediaUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, mediaOptions);
```